# Torsion pendulum and determining the moment of inertia

Tags: experimental-physics, moment-of-inertia

(58. Polish Olympiad in Physics, final stage, 2009)

We have a given element . We have to determine its moment of inertia. The idea is using a torsion pendulum. Some considerations lead us to a formula
$$I = ml^2 \frac {l_x} {l_1}$$
where $m$ is mass of the element, $I$ - the searched moment of inertia, $l_x$ is length of a mathematical pendulum of the same time period as the constructed torsion pendulum and $l, l_1$ are as shown on the picture

[image: Picture 1]

We don't know the mass $m$, though, so we hang small pieces of metal of mass $m_p$ each below the element, as shown on the picture.
Then we get the formula
$$I = (m + n m_p)l^2 \frac {l_x} {l_1}$$
and from here
$$I -n m_p \frac {l^2l_x(n)} {l_1} =m l^2 \frac {l_x(n)} {l_1} $$
$$I + A(n) = m l^2 B(n) $$
where $A(n) = -n m_p \frac {l^2l_x(x)} {l_1}$, $B(n) =\frac {l_x(n)} {l_1} $

Now it is claimed that if we create a diagram with $A(n)$ on the $y$ axis and $B(n)$ on the $x$ axis, we'll get a line and that we can get the wanted moment of inertia from the point of intersection of this line with the $y$ axis.

Why? How can this be justified?

Comment: $l_1$ is not marked in the diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course if we had $B(n) = 0$, then $I = -A(n)$. So if we extrapolate the function $A(n)$, we can get its value for $B(n) = 0$. Hence we get the needed moment of inertia